# Css Transition on hover for child element

Tags: css, parent-child, css-transitions

Im trying to pause the display of a child element when it's parent is hovered over.

Html:

```
<span>
    <div>This Is The Child</div>
    Some Text in the span
</span>
```

Css:

```
span { 
    position: relative; 
}
span div { 
    display: none;
    width: 0px;
    opacity: 0;

    transition: width 5s;
    -webkit-transition: width 5s;

    transition: opacity 5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 5s;
}
span:hover div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}​
```

As of right now, when the span is hovered, the div has no delay before it is shown. How would I go about fixing it so there is a pause?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SReject/vmvdK/

A few notes:
I originally tried to transition the display, but as Edward pointed out, that isn't possible, and have sense tried the above which, also, isn't working

**SOLVED**

It would appear that any "display" property in the "transition to" styling will stop any transition animations from happening. To work around this. I set the width of the child to be displayed to 0px and have it be completely transparent. Then in the "transition to" styling, I set the correct width, and make the div solid:

Html:

```
<span>
    <div>This Is The Child</div>
    Some Text in the span
</span>
```

Css:

```
span { 
    position: relative; 
}
span div { 
    position: absolute;

    width: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 5s;
}
span:hover div {
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}​
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SReject/vmvdK/

Comment: why not the other way around `<div><span>This Is The Child</span>Some Text in the DIV</div>`? ... it's more semantically correct.

Comment: It's for a GM script, the span is created by the site the GM script modifies. I want to create a hover menu for the displayed span

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this article](http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/) on CSS transitions, which is referenced by the [MDN page on CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions), the `display` property is not one that can be transitioned:

> There are several properties or values you’ll want to transition, but which are both unspecced and unsupported at the time of writing:
>
> - `background-image`, including gradients
> - ...
> - `display` between none and anything else

So applying the `transition: display 5s;` property to your `div` has no effect.

EDIT:

Based on your updated code, you can achieve the effect you want with opacity and width as long as you don't specify the `display` property. Simply remove the line

```
display: none;
```

from the `span div` section, and the pop-up menu will use the transitions you specified when you hover over it.

Since the transition from `display:none;` to `display:inline-block` can't be animated, this property is probably changed only at the end of the transition - so the opacity animates while the `div` is still invisible.

Comment: jQuery/JS is the only solution?

Comment: Well, I've updated the fiddle to use a mix of opacity and width transitions and it still isn't working

Comment: You might want to update your question to include the code in your updated fiddle.

Comment: @Edward I did; well atleast the minimum. I saw no reason to put unrelated stylings in the question's code blocks. :)

Comment: @SReject OK, and I updated my answer. (Not sure if it alerts you when I make an edit, since it doesn't count as a "new answer").

Comment: I figured it out before I read your comment but I do appreciate your time :)

Comment: @SReject Great! If you want to answer your own question, the correct format to do it on StackOverflow is to post an answer (you can click the "answer" button on your own questions) and leave your original post as a question. Then you can click "accept" to accept your own answer.

Comment: @SReject You can undo your own edits, or you can wait for the edit I submitted (restoring your original question) to be approved by the Moderators.

Comment: Even though it's been revised, Im going to upvote your answer because it is the same conclusion I came to

Comment: You should not wrap a block level element inside an inline one (span>div). It's not valid.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using `-webkit-transition-delay: ;`? If not, this might be something you are looking for?

Did some changes in the code:

```
span div { 
position: absolute;
left: 5px;
top: 5px;
border: 1px solid #000;
background-color: #888;
width: 0px;
opacity: 0;
cursor: pointer;
```

}

```
span:hover div {
display: inline-block;
-webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
width: 150px;            
opacity: 1;
```

}​

And here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j6RHS/)