# firefox doesn't apply css transitions to child elements

Tags: css, firefox, transition

In Chrome and Safari, the CSS transition is applied to `.divisions a` as well as its child `img` and `span` -- the image gets larger and the caption fades in. Firefox, however, only transitions `.divisions a` and the child elements jump to their new states without any transition.

I wasn't sure if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371360/changing-parent-elements-positioning-prevents-child-element-css3-transition-in) was the same issue or not. If this can't be fixed in Firefox, is there a workaround for that browser so that transitions are applied to the child elements?

Basic HTML:

```
<nav class="divisions">
    <ul>
        <li class="">
           <a href="#"><img src="./images.png" alt="" width="150" height="150">
             <span>Here's a caption</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Relevant CSS (there's more, pre-transition):

```
.divisions a, .divisions a img, .divisions a span {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.divisions a:hover {
    height: 270px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
.divisions a:hover img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.divisions a:hover span {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/f5FKU/

Comment: Have you tried, for example, instead of `.divisions a:hover { newstate; }`, something like `.divisions a:hover, .divisions a:hover * { newstate; }` ? Or if the link itself is insignificant/non-apparent, just `.divisions a:hover * { newstate; }`

Comment: @Ariane Each child has different properties that will be transitioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that since `overflow` isn't a transitionable property, changing `.divisions a:hover` to `overflow:visible` was breaking the transitions for all the child elements (but not for the `a` itself, strangely enough).

Removing that property was enough to make everything work properly in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/f5FKU/17/

```
.divisions a:hover {
    height: 270px;
    padding: 10px 0;
 /* overflow: visible; */
}
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487490/css-transition-on-hover-for-child-element).

Comment: Thank you for the answer +1 .. I completely forgot `overflow` isn't an animatible property.

Comment: @Adrift If this was the definite solution to your problem, don't forget to accept it as the answer!

Comment: @Ariane: He's the one that asked the question! :p